# Quotient group is ismorphoc to?

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group of non zero complex numbers with respect to multiplication and $P$ is a subgroup of all positive real numbers i.e $P=(R^+,×)$ .What is the quotient group $\frac {G}{P}$.
I dont need the answer but just can somebody tell the homomorphism i shoul use..i guess i has to do something with  modulus function?But still i am not able to define a homomorphism between the appropriate groups.

Comment: Yes the modulus is good. Can you figure out what the kernel is?

Comment: I get it the homorphism should be $f(z)=\frac {z}{|z|}$.with the codomain being group of compex numbers with unit mod.hence for the kernel, $\frac {z}{|z|}=1$ this would be mean that a complex number is equal to a positive real number.is it?

Comment: You got it! Do you see what the quotient is? A well known subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Yes it's positive real numbers..thanx..

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $z \equiv w \bmod P$ iff $z=aw$, with $a \in \mathbb R$, $a>0$. Find a canonical representative for each coset.